# C++14 lambda/function decorator

Tags: c++, c++14, rvalue-reference, lvalue

Can someone explain me, C++ unified reference?
I have this code, which works only with lambda functions, but doesn't work with function pointer. What is the problem?

`

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
};

int func2(const A& ref, int q, int b)
{
    printf("A& ref\n");
    return 1;
}

int func2(A&& ref, int q, int b)
{
    printf("A&& ref\n");
    return 2;
}

int main()
{
    A a;

    auto decorator = [](auto&& function, auto&&... params)
    {
        printf("decor: ");
        std::forward<decltype(function)>(function)(
            std::forward<decltype(params)>(params)...
            );
    };

    // compiled
    decorator([](A&& ref, int a, int b)
        { std::cout << a + b << std::endl; }, 
            A(), 7, 4);

    // error here
    //decorator(func2, a, 7, 6);
    
    return 0;
}
```

`

I expect that line with decorator(func2, a, 7, 6) will not cause a compiler error.

Comment: Your function `func2` has two overloads. A reference/pointer to a function can only refer to _one_ of them. But there is no way to decide which one you mean at the `decorator` call site.

Comment: please include the error message in the question. And please post the code that has the error. Hiding the error behind a `//` is a potential source of confusion, just like any other detail that others have to modify on your code before they can reproduce the problem. See [mcve]

Comment: If you want `decorator` to do the overload resolution, then pass the function overload set wrapped in a lambda, e.g. `decorator([](auto&&... args){ func2(decltype(args)(args)...); }, a, 7, 6);`